# Using Sockets [Windows Phone]

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

in Windows Phone OS 7.1 we can use Sockets ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202870%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). I have Visual Studio for Windows Phone 7 downloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/windows-phone-developer-tools.

There is no information which version of OS it handle. I think, if it is the latest version of Visual Studio there should be no problems with Sockets, but when I declare:
Socket sock;
I got an error:
"The type or namespace name 'Socket' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
It's because i have OS version 7.0 or what? Is there any chance to make sockets work?

Answer (score 2):

Recently in windows phone mango edition only Microsoft implemented the feature for Sockets. So if you need to implement sockets in your application you need to download the latest Windows phone Mango beta developer tools; the rtm version of mango developer tools are not readily available now. so first yo download the new developer tool and then try. This will solve your issue.

Try this link for dwnlding developer tools : 
  http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/D/C/EDCF1B19-3D98-48C3-B176-D20AF072497F/WPSDK71.iso

And you may also need to download and install visual studio service pack for installing WPSDK 7.1 RC